# I can't replace a Widget with a Screen in kivy

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I'm a beginner at kivy, I have an fclass(Widget) that I want it to be a fclass(Screen), but when I tried to make the change all the screen messed up, the code generate some buttons with a for loop, I wish I coud do the same with a float layout, but I want the fclass to stay a screen since I'm building a multiscreen app.

Here is the .py file:

```
import kivy

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty,ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.core.camera import Camera
from kivy.graphics import *
import time
import os 
from pathlib import Path 
#import cv2                                         
import struct
import threading
import pickle

Builder.load_file('the.kv')
  

class fscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.list_of_btns = []


    def create(self):
        self.h = self.height*0.9
        for i in range(4):
            self.h = self.h - self.height*0.1
            self.btn = Button(text='button '+str(i), size=(self.width*0.4,self.height*0.05), pos=(self.width*0.3, self.h), on_press=self.press)
            self.list_of_btns.append(self.btn)
            self.add_widget(self.btn)


    def press(self, instance):
        print(instance.text)


    def delete(self):
        for btns in self.list_of_btns:
            self.remove_widget(btns)


class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
    
        self.screenm = ScreenManager() 

        self.fscreen = fscreen()
        screen = Screen(name = "first screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.fscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)


        return self.screenm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theapp = theapp()                                       #
    theapp.run()
```

The .kv file:

```
<fscreen>
    Button:
        text: 'create'
        size: root.width*0.4, root.height*0.05
        pos: root.width*0.3, root.height*0.1
        on_press: root.create()



    Button:
        text: 'delete'
        size: root.width*0.4, root.height*0.05
        pos: root.width*0.3, root.height*0.2
        on_press: root.delete()
```

How can I make the fclass a screen class without messing up everything ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you be more specific about what exactly is your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that code should work, but it doesn't. A fix is to use `size_hint` instead of `size` in both your `kv` and `py`. So the `kv` could look like:

```
<fscreen>:
    Button:
        text: 'create'
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.05
        # size: root.width*0.4, root.height*0.05
        pos: root.width*0.3, root.height*0.1
        on_press: root.create()



    Button:
        text: 'delete'
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.05
        # size: root.width*0.4, root.height*0.05
        pos: root.width*0.3, root.height*0.2
        on_press: root.delete()
```

and in the `create()` method:

```
def create(self):
    self.h = self.height * 0.9
    for i in range(4):
        self.h = self.h - self.height * 0.1
        self.btn = Button(text='button ' + str(i), size_hint=(0.4, 0.05),
                          pos=(self.width * 0.3, self.h), on_press=self.press)
        self.list_of_btns.append(self.btn)
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
```

Your `size` in the `kv` and `py` were both just trying to do the `size_hint` anyway.

And, of course, your `build()` method must be adjusted:

```
def build(self):
    self.screenm = ScreenManager()

    self.fscreen = fscreen(name="first screen")
    self.screenm.add_widget(self.fscreen)

    return self.screenm
```

Other things to note:

- You should use upper case for class names. Failure to do so can lead to errors in `kv`
- You should consider using `pos_hint` instead of `pos` to allow better resizing of your App

Comment: It didn't work, actually the code that I posted works fine, the problem is when I change the fscreen from (Widget) to (Screen) the buttons look all messed up, also the size_hint didn't solve the problem, actually even if I leave the fscreen class as f screen(Widget) it still didn't work as the window still looks messed up in a different way, and even if I try to modify the size_hint value, nothing changes.

Comment: Odd. The changes I suggested worked perfectly for me.